# Merging multiple fields with same parcel id yet different attribute values, while keeping all fields?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, merge, spatial-join, dissolve

I am using ArcGIS 10.3 for Desktop.

I have a property parcel layer that when Intersected, each parcel is broken up into hectares of different land covers. My question is can this be merged (or something similar) back into one attribute with each field populated with the different hectares? Might be a very vague question but it looks similar to this.

```
parcelID     field1      field2      field3      field4       field5

[1]            0           60          0       =[field2] 60     0

[1]            0           0           42          0        =[field1]+[field3] 67

[1]            25          0           0           0        =[field1]+[field3] 67
_________________________________________________________________________________

parcelID     field1      field2      field3      field4       field5  

[1]            25          60          42      =[field2] 60 =[field1]+[field3] 67
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a dissolve.  This just looks like calculations on fields.  Is there only one feature class involved here?  Are you sure you mean ObjectID?  ObjectIDs are unique within a feature class.  What you propose is possible, but I think you need to clarify your question a bit before we can give you a proper answer.

Comment: are all the values currently in different fields, or are they all the same field which you'd want split into different fields when the features are dissolved?